# What installation dependencies/options are needed for graph-tool to include draw_hierarchy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph-tool

I've installed graph-tool 2.26 on ubuntu 14.04, python 3.5.4.

I can use graph-tool, but it seems incomplete.

For example I've seen this error:

`AttributeError: module 'graph_tool.draw' has no attribute 'draw_hierarchy'`

Before installing, I made sure that all the dependencies (found here https://git.skewed.de/count0/graph-tool/wikis/installation-instructions#manual-compilation) were installed, but I may have run into a situation where something was installed but not found/properly linked during install.

Given that `draw_hierarchy` can't be found, is it obvious which dependencies might be missing or of an inappropriate version?

Here's the configuration summary from when I installed graph-tool.

[image: installation configuration summary]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: GTK+ 3

I had GTK+ 3, but apparently not Python GTK+ 3, when I got the error mentioned in the question.

By starting over and doing

```
$ conda install -y -c conda-forge pygobject
$ conda install -y -c ostrokach gtk
```

before installing graph-tool, I was able to gain missing graph-tool functions such as `draw_hierarchy` mentioned in the question.